# Force rollback to entire script (stored procedure included)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, nested, rollback

I have a complex script that contains many stored procedures and I need to do a rollback in all cases.

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
    
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(1);  
    INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(2);  
    
    EXEC storedprocedure1
    
    EXEC storedprocedure2
    
    ....
    
    ROLLBACK;
```

I have not checked all stored procedures inside (if there is or not other transaction).

I ask if there is a way to rollback the entire script (stored procedures included) independently by presence of other transaction inside the stored procedures.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming SQL Server)

There is no need to check inside those stored procedures.

The [`ROLLBACK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-transaction-transact-sql) will rollback all the way to the outer-most transaction, including rolling-back all transactions within `storedprocedure1` and `storedprocedure2`, even if those nested transactions are committed within those procedures.

Selecting [`@@TRANCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trancount-transact-sql) will show you that any `ROLLBACK` sets the transaction count of the session back to 0.

So if you rollback the outer transaction, anyone who may be expecting those nested transactions to commit is [going to be disappointed](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/).